# build g++-mp-6: error: ’-std=c++14’: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, hdf5, macports

I'm trying to install hdf5 with macports using

```
sudo port -s install hdf5 configure.compiler=macports-gcc-8 configure.cxx_stdlib='libstdc++' configure.cxxflags='-std=c++14'
```

However,it fails. By checking hdf5/main.log, the error comes from:

> :info:build g++-mp-6: error: ’-std=c++14’: No such file or directory

Does anyone know what the problem is? Thanks!

Comment: hmm, not 100% sure, but have you tried two dashes? e.g. --std=c++14?

Comment: Thank you! I just tried but still doesn't work. The weird thing is the error also doesn't change, still shown as :info:build g++-mp-6: error: ’-std=c++14’: No such file or directory

Comment: How about use the double quotation marks?